# Correctly reply to comment using textbox array

Tags: php, forum

I'm working on a forum page. Right now what is happening, when a user submits a reply to a topic: that reply gets submitted to all the comments. I need to check to see where the array value is,  compared to the topic. Like for example topic 3, and the user replies: it only replies to that topic, no others.

```
                <form enctype="metadata/form-data" method="post">
                    <?php
                        $reply = $_POST["reply"];
                        $submit = $_POST["submit"];
                        $uID = $newRow["ID"];
                        $cID = $comment["comment_ID"];
                        $ucID = $comment["ID"];

                            //this is where I've been stuck.
                            if(isset($submit)){
                                foreach($reply as $myReply){
                                    echo $myReply.'<br />';
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "No result here.";
                            }
                        ?>
                    <div class="textInput">
                        <textarea name="reply[]" maxlength="255"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submitInput">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="reply" />
                    </div>
                 </form>
```

Comment: This code looks very messy for something so complicated. You're storing images in your DB, huh? Anyway, I'm a tad unsure of what it is you want to achieve exactly. It's also *a lot of code* to read without very clear intentions. Please attempt to summarize your main code better, clean it up and be clearer about what it is exactly that you want to happen.

Comment: It's for a forum. Like how you see on Facebook: you have a ability to make a comment, and to reply to that comment. How do I check for the right comment ID, to insert the reply in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear image of what it is you are using exactly, but I'll make up an example which I'm sure will be of help. I'm going to assume you're using `MYSQLI`

### Steps:

Step 1 ) Store your original post in a table (Original post will be OP from now on)

Step 2 ) Create a table for the replies to go in

Step 3 ) Create a relationship (foreign key)

Step 4 ) Get the original posts you want to be visible (or is it only one?)

Step 5 ) Get related replies

Step 6 ) Put related replies as a sub-array within the OP array.

### Example:

First, get the OP. **STEP 4**

```
<?php
  //In case of multiple:
  $getOP = "SELECT * FROM original_posts WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)";
  //In case of single:
  $getOP = "SELECT * FROM original_posts WHERE ID = 1";
 ?>
```

Now, get those ID's in PHP.

```
<?php 

  //in case of multiple:
  $IDArray = array();
  $getOPResult= mysqli_query($con, $getOP);

  foreach($getOPResult as $row){
    $IDArray[] = $row['ID'];
  }

  //In case of single, no need for a loop
  $result = $getOPResult->fetch_object();
  $OPID = $result->ID;
?>
```

Now, follow up with the replies **STEP 5**

```
<?php

  //In case of multiple
  $getReplies = "SELECT * FROM table_replies WHERE OPID IN(".implode(',', $IDArray).")";

  //In case of single
  $getReplies = "SELECT * FROM table_replies WHERE OPID = $OPID;

?>
```

Now, we'll fuse the arrays. This step isn't even necessary with a single OP:

```
<?php

  $myReplies = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  $fusedArray = array();
  foreach($myReplies as $row){
    //put the replies into an array with the OP's ID as a key
    $fusedArray[$row['OPID']] = $row;
  }

?>
```

### Last step - Rendering it all:

```
<?php 

  $html = '';
  foreach($getOPresult as $OP){
    //set replies array
    $thisOPID = $OP['ID'];
    $relatedReplies = $fusedArray[$thisOPID];

    //From this point on, you can easily loop over the replies for every OP
    $html .= '<div class="myPost">';
    $html .= 'I'm going to output OP data here';
    $html .= '<div class="myReplies">';

    //Start looping over the replies and outputting it here
    foreach($relatedReplies as $reply){
      $html .= 'I'm rendering reply data here';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';
  }

  echo $html;

?>
```

### To close

Now, this isn't extremely specific since I don't have much information, but the logic is there and this logic should suffice in most cases.

Before starting a discussion, please remember that this is just an example of structure and logics.

However you want to output your HTML is on you and so is the coding style. Whether you want to use `procedural mysqli` or not or how you secure it against MYSQL injection and such, are not related to this question and thus should not be discussed. I'm only trying to help OP with the logistics of it all.

Have a nice day, and I hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry, you seem to have changed your question.

In this case, I would simply recommend you to use a hidden field in the form such as this:

`<input type="hidden" name="OPID" value="$IDoftheOP"/>`

Now, whenever load a topic, just fill the value of the hidden input with the ID of it. When reading out the formdata in PHP, simply read it out and that's the ID you need to couple it with.

Comment: Thanks Babydead, that helps. :)